# Can't add image path parameters to HTTP Post Request for Flutter iOS App (400 error)

Tags: flutter, dart, http, post, camera

My flutter page makes an HTTP POST request to the Pl@ntNet API for plant identification. The previous camera screen allows the user to either capture an image or select an image from their phone gallery. And then it passes the path of the image to this page via navigation.

Here's what the [official documentation](https://my.plantnet.org/doc) provided for the POST request params:

```
service: https://my-api.plantnet.org/v2/identify/all
api-key: api-key=YOUR-PRIVATE-API-KEY-HERE
image_1: images=/data/media/image_1.jpeg
image_2: images=/data/media/image_2.jpeg
organ_1: organs=flower
organ_2: organs=leaf
```

For my page, the `service` and `api-key` are preset, but the `image_x` and `organ_x` are determined after an `onPressed`. Here is an example of the map of parameters I made before I send the POST request:

```json
{
    service: https://my-api.plantnet.org/v2/identify/all, 
    api-key: api-key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, 
    organ_1: organs=fruit, 
    image_1: images=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8BF991AE-7288-4B5D-9060-5CA2D6A3C1E3/Documents/camera/pictures/CAP_310365A1-B4D0-4D02-A72C-E8DC80D82529.jpg
}
```

Of course, there can be more images and organs - maximum of 5 according to the documentation.

The issue is, when I make my POST request, the parameters is missing the images. So instead, it looks like this:

```
{
    service: https://my-api.plantnet.org/v2/identify/all, 
    api-key: api-key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, 
    organ_1: organs=fruit
}
```

which results in the request failing with a 400 status code.

So here is the code where I extract the parameters from my map and send the POST request. You can ignore the navigation part since that's not too relevant:

```
  void _navigateToResultPage(BuildContext context) async {
    if (selectedOrgan != null) {
      _addImageAndOrganToParams(); // create the plantnetParams map I was talking about
      String url = '$baseUrl$project?api-key=$apiKey'; 

      var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));

      // Add organs, images, service, and api-key to the multipart request
      plantnetParams.forEach((key, value) async {
        if (key.startsWith('organ')) {
          request.fields[key] = value;
        } else if (key.startsWith('image')) {
          String imagePath = value.split('=')[1]; // Extract image path
          File imageFile = File(imagePath);
          if (imageFile.existsSync()) {
            request.files.add(
              // this commented alternative I tried didn't work
              // http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(key, imageFile.readAsBytesSync(),
              //     filename: imagePath),
              await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
                key,
                imageFile.path,
              ),
            );
            debugPrint('IMAGEPATH: $imagePath');
          }
        } else if (key == 'service' || key == 'api-key') {
          request.fields[key] = value;
        }
      });

      try {
        var response = await request.send();

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          var responseData = await response.stream.bytesToString();
          var result = json.decode(responseData);
          debugPrint('Result: $result');

          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => APIResultPage(
                imagePath: widget.imagePath,
                plantnetParams: plantnetParams,
                imageCounter: imageCounter,
                organCounter: organCounter,
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          debugPrint(request.fields.toString());
          debugPrint('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        debugPrint('Exception during POST request: $e');
      }
    } else {
      // Display snackbar saying you have to select an organ first
    }
  }
```

I'm really confused why it's adding everything except the images. My page actually displays the image in a container using `Image.file(File(widget.imagePath))`, which works perfectly fine. So i'm not sure why it's not adding the image parameters. Is it something to do with the image path? Is it a temp path?

If anyone could provide some insight, it would be greatly appreciated as I've been stuck on this issue for a while now.

One thing I want to mention is that when I search for the image in my terminal, it doesn't exist. When I go into /var/mobile, the Containers directory doesn't exist. Instead, there is just a Libary directory. But then how come I can display the image on the screen with no issue?

Comment: hi there, Pl@ntNet dev here, did you find the solution?